# How to iterate over all possible negative states of a list

Tags: python, iteration

I would want to iterate through every possible possible list where the values in them alternate in negativity. For example,

Given an input of [1, 2, 3]

It should iterate over

[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, -3], [1, -2, 3], [1, -2, -3], [-1, 2, 3], [-1, 2, -3], [-1, -2, 3], [-1, -2, -3]

It would be ideal to do this with iteration instead of recursion because this has to be as fast as possible, also having it done in vanilla python is better than using something like itertools.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Would you please provide your code and what didn't work? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why is reinventing the wheel better than using the standard library?

Answer (score 2):

Start by generating all possible 3-element groups of `1` and `-1`. Then apply pairwise multiplication between such a group and your input:

```
from itertools import product


for signs in product([1,-1], repeat=3):
    print([sign*value for sign, value in zip(signs, input)])
```

Answer (score 1):

using list comprehension and `done in vanilla python`. What it is doing

1. For the number of elemets in the list (in this case 3), it is generating binary sequence like `000`, `001`, `010`...`111`, the it is just a matter to multiply like
   `1*(-1)^0 , 2*(-1)^0, 3*(-1)^1` for a particular combination of `001`

```py
l = [1, 2, 3]

[[j[0]*(-1)**int(j[1]) for j in zip(l, bin(i)[2:].zfill(len(l)))] for i in range(2**len(l))]
```

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, -3],
 [1, -2, 3],
 [1, -2, -3],
 [-1, 2, 3],
 [-1, 2, -3],
 [-1, -2, 3],
 [-1, -2, -3]]
```